# COUNTIFS with two conditions with date range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to conduct a formula to get out two conditions...

Having the below set of data:

[image]

In here, I want to include all of this table range, but I want the countif to only output a count of the engineer with a certain date range.

For example, I want to count how many engineers are in this table UP TO 05/01/2023 (this date will be referenced in another cell, as per screenshot)

It should report out
John Smith , 2
Emily Hill , 2
Jess Ridd, 1

Is anyone able to help me out with a formula?

| Max Reporting Date |
| --- |
| 1/5/2023 |

| Engineer | Date |
| --- | --- |
| John Smith | 01/01/2023 |
| Emily Hill | 02/01/2023 |
| Jess Ridd | 03/01/2023 |
| John Smith | 04/01/2023 |
| Emily Hill | 05/01/2023 |
| Jess Ridd | 06/01/2023 |
| John Smith | 07/01/2023 |
| Emily Hill | 08/01/2023 |
| Jess Ridd | 09/01/2023 |
| John Smith | 10/01/2023 |
| Emily Hill | 11/01/2023 |

Answer (score 1):

Try using <kbd>COUNTIFS( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,A5:A15,
     b,B5:B15,
     ua,UNIQUE(a),
     VSTACK({"Engineer","Counts"},
     HSTACK(ua,COUNTIFS(a,ua,b,"<="&A2))))
```

---

A short one would be like this without using <kbd>LET( )</kbd>

[image]

---

```
=HSTACK(UNIQUE(A5:A15),COUNTIFS(A5:A15,UNIQUE(A5:A15),B5:B15,"<="&A2))
```

---